# Smelling Besamim before Havdallah

Tags: halacha, havdalah, soul

**According to our minhag that we smell Besamim during Havdallah as part of Havdallah**, if one smelled Besamim after Shabbos before Havdallah (for whatever reason), should or can that person omit the Besamim blessing when they recite Havdallah?

Comment: +1 Nice question. This is especially important as we are told to smell them before the blessing in a case of doubt if they still smell. (That might even be an answer actually)